Encrypt and decrypt resource.data.value in firestore rule
I am making a functionality in which when a user will hit a particular node it will check the request.auth.token.crc is equal to the value stored in the resource.data.crc as I need to encrypt the resource.data.crc because the value in request.auth.token.crc also encrypted, I want to check if both values are same.
match /testcrc/{testId} {
     allow read: if request.auth.token.crc == hashing.sha256(resource.data.crc.utf8());
}

Here the hashed value for request.auth.token.crc is
9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08 

and resource.data.crc is test

What isn't working about what you shared? Is there an error message?

no error message i am getting missing permission error when i try to access node

no error message i am getting missing permission error when i try to access node what i want is i will be sending an encrypted sha256 value in auth.token.crc and in db the value will be stored in plain text so i want to encrypt the value stored in db to compare both are equal

const crypto = require('crypto');
// Replace 'test' with the plaintext value you want to hash
const plaintext = 'test';
// Compute the SHA-256 hash of the plaintext and convert to uppercase
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(plaintext).digest('base64url')
console.log('Computed Hash:', hash);
this is what I am using to generate hash for
